# Unable to access Form1 on button click of form2

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

My application is having 2 forms in windows form application (vc++). My first form is Form1.h and second is form2.h. What I am trying to do is calling form2 on the click of button1 (which is on the Form1.h). For calling form2 from Form1 I have used this code

```
#include “Form1.h”
......
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 form2^ fm=gcnew form2;
                 fm->Visible=true;
                 this->Visible=false;
             }
```

This is working fine. But I am unable to call the Form1 on the click of the button (Which is on form2). As soon as I m including Form1.h in the form2.h file, It is giving the following error:-

```
>d:\vs\testformapp\testformapp\Form1.h(81): error C2065: 'form2' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\vs\testformapp\testformapp\Form1.h(81): error C2065: 'fm' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\vs\testformapp\testformapp\Form1.h(81): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'form2'
1>d:\vs\testformapp\testformapp\Form1.h(82): error C2065: 'fm' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\vs\testformapp\testformapp\Form1.h(82): error C2227: left of '->Visible' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

And I just want Form1->Visible=true; on the button click of the form2. I don’t want to Initialize Form1 on the button click of form2 because it will initialize all parameters of form1 and my application requirement is not like that.

Can anybody please tell me any solution for this problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to move this method to a .cpp file so you can properly #include the form .h files.  Avoid investing too much time in C++/CLI Winforms apps, they are no longer supported in VS2012.